# FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory while building an angular 8 project

Tags: angular, package, upgrade, heap-memory, memory-size

I upgraded my angular project from version 4 to version 8. when i run command

> npm start using "start": "node --max_old_space_size=16000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"

i got successful result but when i do run ng build using

> node --max_old_space_size=16000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --aot

I get error mentioned in the title.I tried every possible ways that I could find but still unable to find solution.

my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "eppm",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node --max_old_space_size=16000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "node --max_old_space_size=16000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --aot",
    "fix-memory-limit": "cross-env LIMIT=16000 increase-memory-limit",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "0.0.40",
    "@angular/animations": "8.2.10",
    "@angular/common": "8.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.2.10",
    "@angular/core": "8.2.10",
    "@angular/forms": "8.2.10",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.2.10",
    "@angular/router": "8.2.10",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "5.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "8.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "2.0.0",
    "@types/date-fns": "^2.6.0",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.91",
    "angular-calendar": "0.27.19",
    "angular-font-awesome": "2.0.3",
    "angular-fusioncharts": "^2.0.4",
    "calendar-utils": "0.7.0",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "d3": "^4.12.2",
    "date-fns": "1.30.1",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "fusioncharts": "^3.13.3-sr.1",
    "increase": "^1.0.0",
    "limit": "0.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.20",
    "ng-bootstrap": "1.6.3",
    "ng2-checklist": "1.0.2",
    "ng4-loading-spinner": "^1.0.27",
    "ngx-loading": "^1.0.14",
    "primeng": "4.3.0",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "rxjs": "6.5.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.3",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.8",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^0.4.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "8.2.10",
    "@angular/language-service": "8.2.10",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "6.0.60",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "increase-memory-limit": "^1.0.3",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.1.0",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "protractor": "5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "3.2.0",
    "tslint": "5.3.2",
    "typescript": "3.5.3"
  }
}
```